# Angular 6 mathjax not working

Tags: angular, mathjax

I have project in angular 6. I have installed Mathjax by running following command

`npm install mathjax` and `npm install --save @types/mathjax`

I have created directive

```
    import { Directive, Input, OnChanges, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    @Directive({
      selector: '[Mathjax]'
    })
    export class MathjaxDirective implements OnChanges {

      @Input('Mathjax') private value: string;

      constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
      }


      ngOnInit() {
        this.update();
      }

      ngOnChanges() {
        this.update();

      }

      update() {

        this.element.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.value;
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', MathJax.Hub, this.element.nativeElement]);

      }

    }
```

I am using this directive

```
<span [Mathjax]="mathjaxTest"></span>
```

Its Showing no error in console and its not working. **It is printing the mathjax string instead of making mathematical equation**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import MathJax in your directive.

```
import * as Mathjax from 'mathjax';
```

Comment: its showing error . 'g:/../mathjax-test/node_modules/@types/mathjax/index.d.ts' is not a module.